# How can I display something in the console if I clicked on an event in fullcalendar?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

In config:

```
 select: this.handleManualSelect.bind(this),
      dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this),
      eventClick: info => {
        console.log(info, 'click');
      },
      eventMouseEnter: info => {
        console.log(info, 'enter');
      },
      eventMouseLeave: info => {
        console.log(info, 'leave');
      },
      eventDidMount: info => {
        console.log(info, 'DidMount');
      },
```

When I try to click on the event, nothing is displayed in the console, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "doesn't work". What exactly did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? The [unselect](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselect-callback) callback happens _after_ the selection has been cleared. There's no way to cancel the unselect action from the callback.

Comment: `My goal is to display a popup when clicking on an already existing event`...ok well in that case, you probably need [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick). Selecting and unselecting is about clicking on empty areas of the calendar, it has nothing to do with clicking on existing events. Please study the documentation in a bit more detail.

Comment: @ADyson eventClick doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work how? For what exactly? eventClick definitely _does_ work, if you use it correctly - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNoBQXM - in that example you can click on any event see the alert generated by the callback. If you have a problem, you need to show your code, and ensure that what you provide is a [mre] of the issue. If you show nothing and just say "it doesn't work", we cannot help you.

Comment: @ADyson how to make eventClick in angular? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular  there is no example here

Comment: The same way as you handle any other callback. It gives an example of handling dateClick... the concept is exactly the same as that.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem - demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-field-lnkzy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts . The click works fine. Please provide a [mre] of your issue, otherwise there isn't much we can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the click listener to options. It works. Perhaps some other configurations or how your project is set up is causing this.

```js
calendarOptions = {
 //...
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Sample event',
        start: moment(),
        end:moment().add(30, 'minutes'),
        resourceId: 1
      }
    ],
    eventClick: (info) => {
      console.log(info)
    },
  };
```

```js
{
allDay: false
className: []
end: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _fullCalendar: true, …}
resourceId: "1"
resourceIds: null
source: constructor {calendar: constructor, className: Array(0), uid: '1', eventDefs: Array(1), rawEventDefs: Array(1), …}
start: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _fullCalendar: true, …}
title: "Sample event"
_id: "_fc1"
}
```

Find the sample calendar event and click on it.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fullcalendar-issue-cun3ms?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I can't get events to work as Joosep.P did either. However, the docs do explain that bind is required for the Angular FullCalendar.

```
  options: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
    },
    // customButtons: {
    //   myCustomButton: {
    //     text: 'custom!',
    //     click: function () {
    //       alert('clicked the custom button!');
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
    // timeZone: 'UTC',
    // initialDate: '2022-01-01', // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate
    // weekends: true,
    // editable: true,
    // selectable: true,
    // selectMirror: true,
    // dayMaxEvents: true,
    // eventTextColor: 'grey',
    // eventBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    // dayMaxEventRows: 4,
    eventClick: this.onEventClick.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick
    eventsSet: this.onEventsSet.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventsSet
    dateClick: this.onDateClick.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick
    eventAdd: this.onEventAdd.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAdd
    eventChange: this.onEventChange.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventChange
    eventRemove: this.onEventRemove.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRemove
    select: this.onSelect.bind(this), // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback
    // initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
    events: [
      // { start: '2020-08-30', end: '2020-09-04' },
    ],
    ...

   // one example method
  onEventClick(clickInfo: EventClickArg): void {
    console.log(clickInfo);
    // Remove an event with an event object
    clickInfo.event.remove(); // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove
  }
```

And obviously you'd have to click an event, not just anywhere in the cal.